# How to get http from string?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
"http://add.co" id="num_1"
```

How can I get only `"http://add.co"` from this string?

I tried to use pattern:

```
^http:\/\/(+s)*
```

Comment: Try `explode(" ", $str)[0]`. Or can there be strings with no URL at the start? Then try `'~^"?https?://\S+)*~'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php this will help you out.

Comment: I confused with your question.what you want `http` or `http://add,co`.. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want:

With [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$str = '"http://add.co" id="num_1"';
preg_match('/^"(.*?)"/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

With [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$str = '"http://add.co" id="num_1"';
$url = str_replace("\"", "", explode(" ", $str)[0]);
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex `^"http:\/\/[^"]+(?=")` which almost captures your url.

```
String : "http://add.co" id="num_1"
Matches : "http://add.co
```

You could append a last `"` to the match to fix it. Maybe someone can edit my regex to include the last `"`.

See example here: https://regex101.com/r/oppeaQ/1

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

1)The `explode()` function breaks your string into array based on seperator.

2).The `preg_replace()` replaces the contains of string matched with defined regular expression.

```
$string = '"http://add.co" id="num_1"';
$array = explode(':',$string);
echo preg_replace('/\"/','',$array[0]);
```

Output:

```
http
```

AND

```
$string = '"http://add.co" id="num_1"';
$array = explode(' ',$string);
echo preg_replace('/\"/','',$array[0]);
```

Output:

```
http://add.co
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = '"http://add.co id="num_1"';
preg_match_all('/[a-z]+:\/\/\S+/', $string, $matches);
print($matches[0][0]);
?>
```

o/p

http://add.co //tested in my machine